# Are selenium browser drivers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge, etc) for node.js compiled OS arch or for actual PC processor arch or installed OS arch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

Reading about Node.js's `os.arch()`, it says:
 **returns the operating system CPU architecture for which the Node.js binary was compiled. Possible values are 'arm', 'arm64', 'ia32', 'mips', 'mipsel', 'ppc', 'ppc64', 's390', 's390x', 'x32', and 'x64'.**

Reading this issue
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/17036 stipulates that `os.arch() returns the architecture of the Node.js process, not the operating system.`

When considering downloading selenium browser drivers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge, etc), are we to consider the `node.js compiled OS architecture` **or** for `actual PC installed OS architecture`?

**Example:**

Should I download **chromedriver_win32.zip** for a Node.js compiled for x32 arch (Even if this node is installed on a 64bit OS) or for the installed 32bit Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

You can download executable that is compatible with your operating system. Webdriver itself and programming language bindings are independent. As per WebDriver w3c specification:

> WebDriver remote ends must provide an HTTP compliant wire protocol where the endpoints map to different commands.

So that webdriver exposes HTTP-compliant protocol which decouples your particular binding implementation from implementation of webdriver.